# How to get values of an array of dictionary from alamofire response?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to extract "ArticleID" and "Title" from below json response using Alamofire and swift.

```
[
"MetaTitle": <null>, "IsFeatured": 1, "EndDate": <null>, "LastUpdateID": 8684, 
"DnnForge_NewsArticles_Page": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6080000109b0>(
{
ArticleID = 4649;
PageID = 4649;
PageText = "&lt;a href=&quot;/kshnezam/Portals/0/Users/236/84/8684/\U0628\U0648\U062f\U062c\U0647 97.zip&quot;&gt;\U0628\U0648\U062f\U062c\U0647 97.zip&lt;/a&gt;";
SortOrder = 0;
Title = "\U0628\U0648\U062f\U062c\U0647 \U067e\U06cc\U0634\U0646\U0647\U0627\U062f\U06cc \U0633\U0627\U0644 97 \U0633\U0627\U0632\U0645\U0627\U0646";
}
)
, "IsApproved": 1, "PageHeadText": <null>, "FileCount": 0, "RatingCount": 0, 
"Title": بودجه پیشنهادی سال 97 سازمان, "RssGuid": <null>, "CommentCount": 
    0, "IsNewWindow": 0, "CreatedDate": 2018-01-25T13:17:04.493,
"LastUpdate": 2018-01-25T13:17:22.87, 
"ArticleID": 4649, "MetaKeywords": <null>, "AuthorID": 8684, "ShortUrl": <null>, "ModuleID": 422, "StartDate": 2018-01-24T13:14:00, "ImageUrl": <null>, "MetaDescription": <null>, "PageCount": 1, 
"DnnForge_NewsArticles_ArticleCategories": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6080000114f0>(
{
ArticleID = 4649;
CategoryID = 2;
}
)
]
```

I'm new to swift and I can't find a way to achieve this.
How can I get the values of "ArticleID" and "Title" ?

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/getNews").responseJSON { response in

    }
```

Comment: can you add formatted Json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need something like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/getNews").responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let result):

        let resultsArray = result as! [AnyObject]
        let resultDic = resultsArray[0] as! [String: Any] // I'm using just the first one.
        let articleID = resultDic["ArticleID"] as! Int // (I assume) 
        let title = resultDic["Title"] as! String

       // I'm just creating the let with the values, from here depends on your implementation. 

    default:
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Be sure that the fields are not empty on your response, in this case forcing the unwrap will crash the app.

Comment: The line result as! [String:Any] gives the error : Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x107848dd8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1078492d8).